# Dynamic Magento Grid built with database query

Tags: sql, collections, dynamic, magento, grid

This is my first time asking a question here so, be nice;p .. I'm working with Magento (and Zend Framework) for the first time and I'm trying to build a custom grid that will populate based off of a manually written query. I'm trying to extend the Mage_Core_Model_Mysql4_Collection_Abstract to allow a query to be loaded into it and then parse the select fields in the extended Grid class to make it dynamic... Is this even possible or am I beating a dead horse? I've been at it for a week now and I'm not getting anywhere. The problem seems to be that inside the __Model_mysql4_Collection class has to be initialized with a resource model using _init() in the constuct

Answer (score 3):

As a learning exercise use [the module creator](http://www.magentocommerce.com/extension/1108/modulecreator) to make an admin grid page and see how that is done. Or even modify it's output to get what you need.

There will be a grid container block, a grid block (with `_prepareCollection` and `_prepareColumns` methods), a model, a resource model (representing a single record) and a collection resource model (representing several records).

Providing your own `_init` methods shouldn't be any sort of problem. Perhaps you'd like to post your config.xml and code so far as a pastebin or something.